# How to make the background.js script run in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to creating chrome extensions and I just want to get all cookies from the sites that I visit.  The issue is that when I load a site nothing happens.  I get no errors and no logs for the cookies that I want to get.  Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "xxxxxxxx",
    "version": "0.8",
    "permissions": [
        "cookies",
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

background.js

```
function cookieInfo(){
    chrome.cookies.getAll({}, function (cookies){
        console.log(cookies)
    });
}

cookieInfo();
```

Comment: Is the function even running?

Comment: @Barmar I don't think so, honestly not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: Then it sounds like your question is actually how to make the background script of a chrome extension run. The cookie stuff is irrelevant.

Comment: @Barmar ok I will update my question.

Comment: Maybe it should be a content script rather than a background script.

Comment: @Barmar what's the difference?

Comment: The background script needs to register a listener for an API event, otherwise it rarely makes sense to use a background script. Your current code will run only once when the extension runs on browser startup or after it was re-enabled or re-installed. In other words it doesn't do anything particularly useful. Depending on your preferred method of learning you may want to start with the documentation/tutorial or just inspect the official [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Comment: @wOxxOm I was able to find a good resource that helped me solve this issue.  Sloreti's solution is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background scripts do not log to a specific web page's console. Visit [chrome://extensions/](http://chrome://extensions/) and click on "Inspect views background page" for your extension.

[image]

Comment: Will the logs show in there?

Comment: Yup, that is correct